# No emitters found for type ext-json

Tags: jquery, django, extjs, django-piston

I have this error "**No emitters found for type ext-json**" in running my django...
i dont have any idea about my situation.

i just followed this tutorial and the example is good.
http://weblog.mattdorn.com/content/restful-web-apps-with-django-piston-and-ext-js/

i have followed on making handlers.py, emmiters.py and the others step...

this my url.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from piston.resource import Resource
from phonebook.api.handlers import PhonebookHandler

phonebook_handler = Resource(PhonebookHandler)

urlpatterns=patterns('',
    url(r'^phonebooks/(?P<id>\d+)/$',phonebook_handler, {'emitter_format': 'ext-json'}),
    url(r'^phonebooks$',phonebook_handler, {'emitter_format': 'ext-json'}),
)
```

my emitters.py and handlers.py is same to the tutorial,... the different is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

CHOICES = (
    (u'M', u'Male'),
    (u'F', u'Female'),
)

class Phonebook(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=2,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

is there are any installation about ext-json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your custom emitter class at some point so that it gets registered.

Comment: thanks Daniel, I imported by custom emitter in the api/urls.py and it works, there are some other problem on it but i to solved it..

Comment: the best thing to import the emitter is in the `__init__.py` of the api directory

Comment: Daniel, do you have an idea about this problem? [unable to PUT and DELETE data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147542/unable-to-update-put-and-delete-delete-data-in-django-piston) thanks ...